# Get back object from TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, treeview

I have started learning WPF and I've got question about TreeViewModel and data binding.

I already made my Tree based on this tutorial: [WPF TreeView Tutor](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/) (last example about Family) and now I'd like to know: **is it possible to make binding from TreeView to Object?**

For example - is it possible to select TreeViewItem, find out its type (is it Family or is it FamilyMember) and cast it to proper class?

Comment: You should build a ViewModel. Check out this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688865/wpf-manually-generate-treeviewitem-container/2689051#2689051

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I will focus on ViewModel and hope it helps.